# Exporting a custom RxJS operator in an Angular library

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

The following custom RxJS operator (actually just a .filter equivalent for demonstration) is currently declared in an Angular 4.0.0-rc.2 component.

```
declare module 'rxjs/Observable' {
  interface Observable<T> {
    restrictToCommand<U>(f: (x: T) => U): Observable<U>;
  }
}

Observable.prototype.restrictToCommand = function (cmd) {
  return new Observable((observer) => {
    const obs = {
      next: (x) => {
        if (x.command === cmd) {
          observer.next(x);
        }
      },
      error: (err) => observer.error(err),
      complete: () => observer.complete()
    };
    return this.subscribe(obs);
  });
};
```

This works fine. However, I would like to extract this declaration to a library that is responsible for external communication. The main import of this library is a singleton service.

How to properly export the prototype extension and the module declaration from within that library?

Comment: It's not clear if the operator is already used by the library or just exists for convenience.

Comment: The library itself has no internal use for the operator, it is a convenience function meant for users that import the library.

Comment: Then follow the way that RxJS goes with `rxjs/add/operator/...` and provide `restrictToCommandOperator.js` in package root.

Comment: Thank you, that looks like a valid path. If you were to formulate an answer with a code example (for completeness sake) I'd probably accept it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the operator isn't used by the library itself and exists for user's convenience, it can follow the the way that RxJS goes with `rxjs/add/operator/...`.

Operator definition can be moved to a separate file in package root (`restrictToCommandOperator.js` and `restrictToCommandOperator.d.ts`) and be imported like

```
import 'packagename/restrictToCommandOperator';
```

It should be noted that this will work smoothly only if the package doesn't have `rxjs` dependency with version restrictions. If it does, there's a chance that there may be multiple RxJS package versions per user's project, and `restrictToCommandOperator` won't extend desired `Observable`.